# how to create a secure network connection in Kitkat and Lollipop?

Tags: android, security, connection

In AndroidManifest.xml, using the android:networkSecurityConfig attribute which is works for API level 24 or higher.
Please give solution for API level which is below than 24.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OkHttp and its options for things like certificate pinning](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS).

Or, [use my backport of network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity), though it too works best with OkHttp.

Comment: but i'm using android query library to fetch the data from server.

Comment: @Sam: Then I do not have any options for you. Talk to the developers of that library and see if they can support using OkHttp for the HTTPS communications.

Comment: @Sam: Since Retrofit integrates with OkHttp, you can configure OkHttp using the techniques from my answer, then use that with Retrofit.